# Map a collection of subsets to another collection of smaller cardinality

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, combinations

Assume a set of elements $S = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and its partition into all possible $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of cardinality $k$. Let us call the corresponding collection of subsets of $S$ as $C$. For example for $n=5$, $k=3$
$$C = \{\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,2,5\},\{1,3,4\},\{1,3,5\},\{1,4,5\},\{2,3,4\},\{2,3,5\},\{2,4,5\},\{3,4,5\}\}.$$

In such collections the following properties hold:

- Any element $x\in S$ is in a fixed number of sets in $C$, specifically in $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.
- Any pair of elements $x,y\in S$ is in a fixed number of sets in $C$, specifically in $\binom{n-2}{k-2}$.

Starting from $C$, I want to construct a new collection $C'$ also of subsets of $S = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ each of cardinality $k$. However, $C'$ should have fewer sets than $C$ and should have the properties:

- Any element $x\in S$ is in a fixed number of sets in $C'$.
- Any pair of elements $x,y\in S$ is in a fixed number of sets in $C'$.

I thought of starting using the factorization
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$
where $n,k \neq 0$.

Also suppose that $k|n$. This tells us that one can "group" the sets of $C$ into $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ "groups". Each group can then correspond to a subset of $C'$. However, I don't know how one can constructs these subsets of $C'$ such that the above properties hold. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "construct a new collection"? and "fixed number of sets"? Do you mean that you have numbers $a,b$ such that you want exactly $a$ sets to contain just $x$ and $b$ sets to contain $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @Phicar I need to rephrase it. My entire question is: Given a set of elements $S = \{1,2,...,n\}$ can one construct a collection $C'$ of $k$-subsets of $S$ s.t. (1) $|C'| < \binom{n}{k}$, (2) each $x\in S$ appears in a fixed number of sets in $C'$ and (3) each pair $x,y \in S$ appears in a fixed number of sets in $C'$ ?

Comment: That is what I do not understand. What does "fixed number of sets" mean? You know the number apriori?

Comment: @Phicar No, I do not know the number a priori but as long as it is a constant for any $x\in S$ and for any pair $x,y\in S$ (properties (2),(3) in previous comment), it is fine with me.

Comment: The thing you are trying to construct is known as a [block design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design). There is a lot of theory about these, and even more which is unknown. You could write an entire book answering your question, so I vote this is too broad.

Comment: Yes, it is a very interesting subject, worthy of a more focused Question.  The word [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) is not a good choice unless you are splitting a set $S$ into disjoint subsets whose union is all of the set $S$.

Comment: Please have a look at [previous Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=combinatorics+block+design+is%3Aquestion) about these balanced block 2-designs.  There are fairly [standardized variables for the parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design):  number of times any 2-subset appears in any block is $\lambda$ and this actually implies each element appars an equal number of times when all blocks are the same size.